# Intellij plugin to recognize javascript in a tag

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-13

I am using a template library that our company has developed.

It is really great, however, we are using a tag:

```
<g:js> 

// javascript code

</g:js>
```

This tag does some stuff but essentially that is javascript code with some objects passed to it at the client.

How can I get intellij to recognize this as javascript code? Right not it is being treated as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [Inject language](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-language-injections.html). To do that, move the cursor inside the tags (where your JS code is) and either:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> -> `Inject Language` -> JavaScript
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and type `Inject language`

After that you can customize injection settings using `language injection settings` (again, by using one of those methods).